# Unable to use a hyphen in a Drupal 7 text field

Tags: input-formats, javascript

I've got a simple field of type "text", widget = "text field" (Drupal 7).

I am able to use special characters like &(%, but when I try to type a hyphen, there is no result. I can use a rich text field, but I only want plain text.

I **am** able to use the ASCII code like `S&#45;26` where I really just want `S-26`.

This was not an issue in Drupal 6.

Thanks very much!

Comment: are you using text field with custom form?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot type it, like, literally, keypress on keyboard does nothing? If so, then you have javascript or browser problem. On what browser it happened? What are your results from other browsers?

Or you can type it, and it's just not rendered?

Comment: I have the same problem, I can copy-paste it but can't type it. Weird problem. Could googlemaps (openlayers) maybe cause this javascript problem?

Comment: @Aboodred1, no I am not.

Comment: @Mołot That's a great suggestion. Unfortunately (?), the error seems to have "gone away on its own". I can't test it or reproduce it.

Comment: @Mr.B I am also using OpenLayers, but I can't say now whether that's an issue.

Comment: I can confirm that it had something to do with Openlayers. I removed the map on that page and hyphen and underscores where available again. Did not need/find a good solution for it yet.

Comment: @Mr.B, I wonder if it has something to do with Keyboard Controls on your Map (preset). I just noticed that the hyphen is also the zoom out. It's possible that we were both pressing the zoom out, but if the map was not visible on the screen we wouldn't have noticed it. I'm 99% sure this is the issue. Under "behaviors" in your map settings, disable keyboard controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom behavior of the map is responsible for this unwanted behavior.
You need to disable keyboard controls on the map in your node edit form.
This could be the default map or the default map installed by geofield.

Comment: That was also my finding in the last comment above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution after spending a lot of time in OpenLayers library.
Basically the solution is to create a new behavior which will override the function OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults, after that you will have to comment the lines which use the - and + code keys, and in the end force to render the behavior.

This Solution works for Drupal 7

Create a new module and don't forget to add these 2 lines in the info file:

```
dependencies[] = openlayers
dependencies[] = geofield
```

The new behavior

```
function mymodule_openlayers_behaviors(){
  return array(
    'openlayers_behavior_OKC' => array(
      'title' => t('Override key control'),
      'description' => t('Remove the - and + zoom key'),
      'type' => 'behaviors',
      'behavior' => array(
        'class' => 'openlayers_behavior_OKC',
        'parent' => 'openlayers_behavior',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/includes',
        'file' => 'openlayers_behavior_OKC.inc',

      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

the file includes/openlayers_behavior_OKC.inc will call the js to override the function.

```
class openlayers_behavior_OKC extends openlayers_behavior {
  /**
   * Provide initial values for options.
   */
  function options_init() {
    return array(
      'keyboarddefaults' => '',
    );
  }

  // /**
  //  * Render.
  //  */

  function render(&$map) {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule').'/js/openlayers_behavior_OKC.js');
      return $this->options;
    }

}
```

after that you just need to rewrite the function OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults (I've comment the lines related to the + and - but you can choose or add new keys if you want to)
Here is the file js/openlayers_behavior_OKC.js

```
/**
 * @file
 * JS Implementation of OpenLayers behavior.
 */

/**
 * Keyboard Defaults Behavior.  Implements the KeyboardDefaults OpenLayers
 * Control.
 */
OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {

    /**
     * APIProperty: autoActivate
     * {Boolean} Activate the control when it is added to a map.  Default is
     *     true.
     */
    autoActivate: true,

    /**
     * APIProperty: slideFactor
     * Pixels to slide by.
     */
    slideFactor: 75,

    /**
     * APIProperty: observeElement
     * {DOMelement|String} The DOM element to handle keys for. You
     *     can use the map div here, to have the navigation keys
     *     work when the map div has the focus. If undefined the
     *     document is used.
     */
    observeElement: null,

    /**
     * Constructor: OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults
     */

    /**
     * Method: draw
     * Create handler.
     */
    draw: function() {
        var observeElement = this.observeElement || document;
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Keyboard( this,
                {"keydown": this.defaultKeyPress},
                {observeElement: observeElement}
        );
    },

    /**
     * Method: defaultKeyPress
     * When handling the key event, we only use evt.keyCode. This holds 
     * some drawbacks, though we get around them below. When interpretting
     * the keycodes below (including the comments associated with them),
     * consult the URL below. For instance, the Safari browser returns
     * "IE keycodes", and so is supported by any keycode labeled "IE".
     * 
     * Very informative URL:
     *    http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html
     *
     * Parameters:
     * evt - {Event} 
     */
    defaultKeyPress: function (evt) {
        var size, handled = true;
        switch(evt.keyCode) {
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_LEFT:
                this.map.pan(-this.slideFactor, 0);
                break;
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_RIGHT: 
                this.map.pan(this.slideFactor, 0);
                break;
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_UP:
                this.map.pan(0, -this.slideFactor);
                break;
            case OpenLayers.Event.KEY_DOWN:
                this.map.pan(0, this.slideFactor);
                break;

            case 33: // Page Up. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(0, -0.75*size.h);
                break;
            case 34: // Page Down. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(0, 0.75*size.h);
                break; 
            case 35: // End. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(0.75*size.w, 0);
                break; 
            case 36: // Home. Same in all browsers.
                size = this.map.getSize();
                this.map.pan(-0.75*size.w, 0);
                break; 

/*            case 43:  // +/= (ASCII), keypad + (ASCII, Opera)
            case 61:  // +/= (Mozilla, Opera, some ASCII)
            case 187: // +/= (IE)
            case 107: // keypad + (IE, Mozilla)
                this.map.zoomIn();
                break; 
            case 45:  // -/_ (ASCII, Opera), keypad - (ASCII, Opera)
            case 109: // -/_ (Mozilla), keypad - (Mozilla, IE)
            case 189: // -/_ (IE)
            case 95:  // -/_ (some ASCII)
                this.map.zoomOut();
                break; */
            default:
                handled = false;
        }
        if (handled) {
            // prevent browser default not to move the page
            // when moving the page with the keyboard
            OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
        }
    },

    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults"
});
```